# Can not convert expression's type int to type void swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, size-t

I am trying some obj-c code to swift and this is my obj-c code:

```
NSString *this_device = @"";
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *machine = malloc(size + 1);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
machine[size] = 0;
NSString *machineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", machine];
```

I converted it into swift code:

```
 var this_device : NSString = ""
    var size : size_t?
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size!, nil, 0)
    var machine = malloc(size! + 1)
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size!, nil, 0)
    machine[size] = 0 //Can not convert expression's type 'int' to type 'Void'
```

But I am getting error at `machine[size] = 0`.

I don't understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your code. *First* (as already noticed by SolaWing),
the allocated pointer must be a pointer to `CChar` (aka `Int8`).
This can be done with

```
var machine = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>.alloc(...)
```

or

```
var machine = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>(malloc(...))
```

*Second*, the `size` variable must not be an optional but a an initialized
`size_t` variable which is passed as inout parameter to `sysctlbyname()`:

```
var size = size_t(0)
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
var machine = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>(malloc(size + 1))
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, nil, 0)
machine[size] = 0
let machineString = String.fromCString(machine)!
free(machine)
println(machineString)
```

Alternatively, you can create a Swift array instead of allocating memory,
this has the advantage that the memory is released automatically:

```
var size = size_t(0)
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
var machine = [CChar](count: size + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
machine[size] = 0
let machineString = String.fromCString(machine)!
println(machineString)
```

The above code compiles with Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta).
In Swift 1.1 (Xcode <= 6.2), `size_t` has to be converted to `Int`
at

```
var machine = [CChar](count: Int(size) + 1, repeatedValue: 0)

machine[Int(size)] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

malloc return type is `Void *`, so machine[size] expect a Void type.

you need to use

`var machine = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>.alloc(size!+1)`

to alloc the char* pointer

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am getting another error : `Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied argument`.